# Minimizing Functional with Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I have some functional, such as `S[f] = \int_\Omega f^2(x) dx`. If you're familiar with physics, it's the action. This object takes in a function defined on a certain domain `\Omega` and gives you a number. The math jargon for this is functional.

Now I need to minimize this thing *with respect to* `f`. I know `SciPy` has an optimize package that allows one to minimize multivariable functions, but I am curious if there is a better way considering if I used this I would be minimizing over ~10,000 variables (because the functions are essentially just lists of 10,000 numbers).

Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [symbolic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression) to find the function.
There are several packages available:

- [deap](https://github.com/DEAP/deap)
- [glyph](https://github.com/Ambrosys/glyph)
- [gplearn](https://github.com/trevorstephens/gplearn)
- [monkeys](https://github.com/hchasestevens/monkeys)

Here is a [good paper](https://www3.nd.edu/~msen/Teaching/MathMeth/Reading/Lipson2009.pdf) on symbolic regression by Schmidt and Lipson.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is more designed for doing Neural Network stuff, [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) sounds like it would work for you. It has the ability to differentiate vector equations and also optimize them using gradient descent.